# Find high frequency elements in array in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, find

I have an array called `reducedWords` (nx1) and this array contains the words of my document. I need to find high frequency word, my question is: Is there any function that i can use that? Or should I define my function?

```
reducedWords = allWords;
unneccesaryWords = {'in','on','at','from','with','a','as','if','of',...
                    'that','and','the','or','else','to','an'};
kk = 1;
while kk <= length(reducedWords)
    for cc = 1:length(unneccesaryWords)
        if strcmp(reducedWords{kk},unneccesaryWords{cc})==1
            reducedWords = { reducedWords{1:kk-1} reducedWords{kk+1:end} };
            kk = 1;
        end
    end
    kk = kk + 1;
end
```

Best regards

Comment: You could try [plotting a histogram](http://www.mathworks.it/it/help/matlab/ref/hist.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`tabulate()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/tabulate.html), which creates a frequency table of data in the vector.

Example:

```
words = {'a','a','bb','bb','bb','bb','ccc'};
tab = tabulate(words)
```

Result:

```
  Value    Count   Percent
      a        2     28.57%
     bb        4     57.14%
    ccc        1     14.29%
```

---

Alternatively, you can use [`CountMember.m`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7738-countmember).

Comment: so i should pass my array to this function?

Comment: @user3527150 Yes. Have a try.

Comment: How can i access the first column of this output?I want to return the word with high Freq?

Comment: @user3527150 Simply assign the result to a variable. Then you can get what you need from it. Check the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Approach 1**

**Code**

```
words_cell_array = {'cat' 'goat' 'man' 'woman' 'child' 'man'}
[array1, ~, ind1] = unique(words_cell_array,'stable');
[~,max_ind] = max(histc(ind1, 1:numel(array1)));
max_occuring_word = words_cell_array(max_ind)
```

**Output**

```
words_cell_array = 

    'cat'    'goat'    'man'    'woman'    'child'    'man'


max_occuring_word = 

    'man'
```

**Approach 2**

**Code**

```
words_cell_array = {'cat' 'goat' 'man' 'woman' 'child' 'man'}
[~, ~, ind1] = unique(words_cell_array,'stable');
[~,max_ind] = max(sum(bsxfun(@eq,ind1,ind1'),1));%%//'
max_occuring_word = words_cell_array(max_ind)
```

**Approach 3: If you are looking for some stats about the cell array of words**

**Code**

```
words_cell_array = {'man' 'goat' 'man' 'woman' 'goat' 'man'};
[Words, v1, ind1] = unique(words_cell_array,'stable');
Count = histc(ind1, 1:numel(Words));
Percent = Count*100/numel(words_cell_array);
```

**Output**

```
words_cell_array = 
    'man'    'goat'    'man'    'woman'    'goat'    'man'

Words = 
    'man'    'goat'    'woman'

Count =
     3     2     1

Percent =
   50.0000   33.3333   16.6667
```